# PostgreSQL Convert .sql file to .csv file

Tags: postgresql

In PostgreSQL I have backed up records of Table **`users`** to **`users.sql`**.

After some changes I made to data in other tables in the Database, PostgreSQL is not allowing me to restore the data from **`users.sql`**.

The only workaround available to me at this stage is to convert users.sql to **`.csv`** file and then copy & paste the data into Table **`users`**.

Is there a way to convert PostgreSQL backup file **`users.sql`** to **`users.csv`**?

Comment: You don't specify what error you're getting, but as it's due to changes made to *other* tables, it's presumably a foreign key constraint that is being violated. If so, converting to a CSV will not help - when you try to restore that data, it's still going to run into the same constraint violations.

Comment: Yes, What you say is correct. There is no way that I can go back and undo changes I made in other tables. So the best solution now is to convert `users.sql` to `users.csv`. Hence, looking for a solution to understand the file format of `PostreSQL` `.sql` file or a tool to convert it to `.csv` file format or `.txt` file format. 
So is there a way?

Comment: Not without restoring the table, no. Which is to say, the way to convert a .sql to a .csv is "restore the SQL and then do a CSV export". What about editing the .sql manually to: A) remove any CREATE TABLE/ALTER TABLE statements, B) change the table name being restored to (like, users_no_fks), and then creating a table in your DB with the same columns as users but with no constraints? At that point, you can restore to that FK-less table & then `COPY users_no_fks to /path/to/users.csv CSV HEADER;`.

Comment: The `users.sql` dump file is in Binary format. If it had been text, then there is no issue at all.

Comment: Oh, then it's easy! Use `pg_restore --section=data -f /path/to/new_users.sql /path/to/existing/users.sql`, which will create a new_users.sql with only a COPY statement with the table data. Edit the table name there, create the corresponding FK-less table in your DB, restore & re-export, and you have your CSV. (pg_restore cannot convert to CSV directly; the best you can do is --section=data to get a plain-text dump of just the table data before proceeding with the load & re-export steps.)

Comment: Thanks a Ton Sir. You Made My Day. Its working Fantastic. I Can Recover My Data. God Bless you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [AdamKG](https://stackoverflow.com/users/16361/adamkg). The solution has been given to me by AdmKG.

`pg_restore --section=data -f /path/to/new_users.sql /path/to/existing/users.sql`

For those who didn't understand the `/path/to/`, it is the path to the new target file and `/path/to/existing` is the path where one has saved the `PostgreSQL` `users.sql` file on the hard disk or any other storage media.

This solution is **not** mine but of AdamKG.

This Post is for sake of convenience of other users like me.

Comment: It is extremely unusual to give the result of a "custom" dump file (`pg_dump -Fc ...`)  the extension `.sql`

Comment: The pg4Admin that comes with Postrgres 9.6.6 provides for `BackUp` to `.sql` and `.bak`. 
Once downloaded, the workaround provided by @AdamKG helps in generating a `.sql` file where in the data are `Tab Separated`. The `Tab` values can be searched and replaced with command to convert the data to `.csv` format and restore the data with ease. It worked for me very well. The Best part is that I trained my professional software Developers also on this method of data recovery from `.sql` dump.